# Find text between strings python

Tags: python, regex

I looked at similar question and answers but could not solve my issue.

I have a string, like the following:

```
ecc, ecc, .....thisIsUnique("92781227-7e7e-4768-8ee3-4e1615bddf3c", ecc, ecc.......
```

could be very long before and after without having some *unique* text.

What I need is to get the `92781227-7e7e-4768-8ee3-4e1615bddf3c` code as string. So I'm looking to something that ca sound like:

when you find `thisIsUnique` go ahead, read the code after you find the first `("` characters and keep reading until you find the first `",` characters.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with regex, but maybe there are different ways to solve the problem

thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few sites you should read up on for what regex is. https://regexone.com/ and [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)  Use a site like this to test what you have tried: https://regex101.com/  But to get you started, this runs exactly what you have pasted as an example:

```
import re

text = 'ecc, ecc, .....thisIsUnique("92781227-7e7e-4768-8ee3-4e1615bddf3c", ecc, ecc.......'
match = re.search('thisIsUnique\("([^"]+)', text)
print (match.group(1))
```

result:

```
92781227-7e7e-4768-8ee3-4e1615bddf3c
```

Comment: perfect! work nice. I'll sure have a look also at the links you posted

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search`:

```
In [991]: text = 'ecc, ecc, .....thisIsUnique("92781227-7e7e-4768-8ee3-4e1615bddf3c", ecc, ecc.......'

In [992]: re.search('(?<=thisIsUnique\(")(.*?)"', text).group(1)
Out[992]: '92781227-7e7e-4768-8ee3-4e1615bddf3c'
```

---

```
'(?<=thisIsUnique\(")(.*?)"'
```

Employs a lookbehind.

---

Additional Reading

1. [Regex HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) - getting started with tutorial
2. [General documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)
3. Additional tutorial site - [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)

Comment: @DeepSpace I don't think so?

Comment: @matteo for future reference, where could I improve upon my answer?

Comment: @COLDSPEED you answer is perfect. I just accept the other for the additional links. Thanks again for the patience!

Comment: @matteo Oh... is that so. I believe the most important link for you is the regex howto. I have linked you to that in my answer. Online regex editors are fine but at the end of the day they don't teach you how to use regex.